# Discord.py random syntax error when loading bot.run

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was following a tutorial to learn some new discord.py techniques but when following a tutorial I came across this error which I can't fix, this is the code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from discord.utils import get
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("Nzg4NjQxMTQzNDExNTcyNzk2.X9mdTA.3NrZ87u3cn8-i5icp7AQD1xdmbQ")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/"
bot.run('Nzg4NjQxMTQzNDExNTcyNzk2.X9mdTA.3NrZ87u3cn8-i5icp7AQD1xdmbQ')
```

My problem is that when I run the code I get a syntax error specifically on the `"b"` at the beginning of `bot.run()` any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis at the end of the `commands.Bot` line

Comment: Also please change your token, people can steal your bot and take in control of it.

Comment: @MohammadHosseinZiyaaddini please stop suggesting `inline formatting` for random keywords in your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is exactly what you've posted, you're just missing a `)` at the line before the last.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/" # <-- MISSING PARENTHESIS HERE
bot.run('Nzg4NjQxMTQzNDExNTcyNzk2.X9mdTA.3NrZ87u3cn8-i5icp7AQD1xdmbQ')
```

In cases like this Python throws an error at the line below because it can't understand the previous line has ended.